# Can't use tahoma font

Tags: fonts

I have installed  infinality-bundle to refine font rendering but now I can't use tahoma font. neither my system nor Firefox can read it although it's installed . tahoma font is replaced by DejaVuSansCondensed which is ugly with Arabic webpages . can anyone tell me what is wrong and walk me through my font settings to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1 in your `/home/usr` directory create .fonts directory and place your font into this directory.

2 run `fc-cache -f -v` to rebuild your font cache.

3. This should now allow you to see your font when it is called through an application.

Comment: already did that but no use !